# Share PST file across multiple machines

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, file-sharing

Does anyone have experience sharing one .pst file across multiple Outlook installations?  I want to have one calendar, contacts, etc on multiple machines.  I have several ways to get the file on the machines (VPN windows share, Mesh, etc) but I don't know whether outlook will freak out if another program is modifying the data file or if I'm going to run into problems if both are running at the same time, etc.

Any thoughts?  Also, would one method of sharing be better than another?

Comment: This Q&A is very old, but it showed up currently.  Using a PST over the network is bad idea, even microsoft doesnt recommend it, as it can cause corruption of the PST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot automatically synchronize personal folders (.pst) files between two different computers in Microsoft Outlook. This article describes how you can work around this to have this capability.[SOURCE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291627)

Comment: Thanks for the link. This doesn't really answer my question about concurrent writes though. I know Outlook can't do it but I'm wondering whether a single PST can be used concurrently across multiple machines.

Comment: No it cannot. The link provided will show you how to work around this issue. This will be all you can do is work around the issue. There seems to be software around the internet that claims to do it.